# how to limit SQL query results based on data in second table?

Tags: sql, jpa

I have an existing system with a USERS and GROUPS table.  I have JPA objects for User and Group.

Table USERGROUPS is a mapping of which users are in which groups, this table is not mapped to an object, I pretty much do a straight SQL query on it like so:

```
public List<User> getUsersByGroupId(long groupId) {
  List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
  String query = "select USERGROUPS.USER_ID from USERGROUPS where USERGROUPS.GROUP_ID = ?1";
  Query q = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(query, Long.class);
  q.setParameter(1, groupId);
  List<Long> userIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
  usersIds.addAll(q.getResultList());
  for (Long id : userIds) {
    users.add(getUser(id));
  } 
  return users;
}
```

Everything works fine.

Now I have a new application which wants to use a subset of the Users in the USERS table.

The plan is to add a new table (because we don't want to modify the existing one) called MYAPP_USERS which consists of one column, the USER_ID of the users to list in MYAPP.

So my question is, how to I modify my query to only return members of the group that are in the MYAPP_USERS table?

That is, how do I do:

```
  String query = "select USERGROUPS.USER_ID from USERGROUPS where USERGROUPS.GROUP_ID = ?1 and WHERE ?1 IS IN MYAPP_USERS";
```

?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
select USERGROUPS.USER_ID 
from   USERGROUPS 
where  USERGROUPS.GROUP_ID = ?1 
   AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MYAPP_USERS WHERE USER_ID = ?1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get results only for the users users found in the MYAPP_USERS table, 
start from that table and do an INNER JOIN with USERGROUPS to get their
GROUP_IDs:

```
SELECT usergroups.user_ID
FROM myapp_users INNER JOIN usergroups
ON myapp_users.user_ID = usergroups.user_ID
WHERE usergroups.group_ID = ?1
```

To plan for the future, instead of the myapp table I would make a table app_users with the columns
user_ID and app_ID, and then specify the app_ID in the query:

```
...
WHERE usergroups.group_ID = ?1
AND app_ID = ?2
```